# NSFW alien erotica book about a woman with purple eyes being chased by evil aliens

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens, erotica

I read this book in 2008ish.

This woman is 24 or around this age. She is hidden on Earth to protect her from the evil race called 'c*nt' (a very unfortunate name I know) that want to destroy her planet. She is saved by I think the sexy hunk she ends up losing her virginity to. The people from her planet all have purple eyes. On her planet, she’s supposed to take her rightful place as the princess, but at the same time she’s having a lot of sexy times.

I think this became a series. I can’t remember anything else.

Comment: And you want to find this to read it *again*?

Comment: Not really, I just feel like like it was an easy read easily forgotten and I can’t even remember if it was an actual book or if I stumbled upon some random internet story if that makes sense. And it’s driving my ocd crazy, just looking for an answer my friend.